# Here maps autocomplete js api

Tags: javascript, here-api

Here maps added autocomplete function to its geocoder api

```
http://autocomplete.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json
?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}
&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
&query=Pariser+1+Berl
&beginHighlight=<b>
&endHighlight=</b>
```

It is complete new and not well documented right now. I do not know how to call it with js api. Do anybody use it with the js api or know how to use it with js api?

Most js api acts as wrapper class for geocorder, so i want to prefer using existing wrapper before building my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a project to wrap the HERE Maps JS API, you can find it on NPM here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-heremaps

If you're looking to display maps in the browser, I've started working on a project for a React integration here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-here-maps

And you can of course just include the HERE Maps script directly.

Answer (score 1):

For a full working example see fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/Lhj2mnpd/.

```
https://autocomplete.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?query=1+Main+Street&app_id=hereid&app_code=herecode&beginHighlight=%3Cb%3E&endHighlight=%3C%2Fb%3E
```

Answer (score 0):

The HERE Maps JS API doesn't seem to have an existing wrapper for it (yet?). Easiest thing would probably be to call the URL via jQuery ([$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)) or some such until it's integrated. The JS API doesn't do much more than create a JSON-P request and hand you the result back...

Answer (score 0):

```
https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoding_suggestions/geocoding-autocomplete
```

> Refer To This Link For Further Demo and Implementation

Answer (score 0):

Moving forward with your code 
Just Replace
your purchased api key and code like

```
http://autocomplete.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?app_id={"purchasedappid here "}&app_code={"purchased appcode here "}&query=Pariser+1+Berl&beginHighlight=&endHighlight=`
```